# Making PreferenceScreen not write to default SharedPreferences

Tags: android

I have a PreferenceScreen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxHighlightWeekends"
        android:key="checkBoxHighlightWeekends"
        android:summary="Weekends are different"
        android:title="Highlight weekends" />

    <MultiSelectListPreference
        android:id="@+id/multiSelectListSelectWeekends"
        android:key="multiSelectListSelectWeekends"
        android:dialogTitle="Select weekends"
        android:entries="@array/weekends"
        android:entryValues="@array/weekends_values"
        android:summary="Saturday, Sunday"
        android:title="Select weekends"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I'm trying to use only the "view" part of this and not make it write to it's default SharedPreferences. When user changes the preference, I manually check the changed data and send it to a MVVM repo, when then writes to my own custom SharedPreference. I plan to use LiveData to update the settings screen when it's opened. All this hassle because I'm trying to learn the MVVM architecture and Android in general.

> Inside MainPreferenceFragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_main);

    CheckBoxPreference checkBoxHighlightWeekends = getPreferenceManager().findPreference("checkBoxHighlightWeekends");
    MultiSelectListPreference multiSelectListPreference = getPreferenceManager().findPreference("multiSelectListSelectWeekends");

    checkBoxHighlightWeekends.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(changeListener);
    multiSelectListPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(changeListener);
}

Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener changeListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
        // Call method in ViewModel which will save settings state to SharedPrefs
        Logger.alert("Something changed! " + preference.getKey());
        return true;
    }
};
```

Any change to settings triggers the function, however the checkbox stops working - It doesn't change to the "tick" state anymore.

How can I strip out all the default click/change functionality from the PreferenceScreen and make it into a dumb view?

Comment: you mean to disable the checkbox?

Comment: @DarShan Nope, just want it to behave as a regular Checkbox, but after adding the changeListener the checkBox doesn't change it's state on click. The checkbox isn't disabled either.